# How is time used in this autocorrelation expression?

Tags: autocorrelation, theory

There are two papers I'm working through that explain applications of autocorrelation.

The [first](http://193.166.3.2/pub/sci/audio/dafx/2000/profs.sci.univr.it/%257Edafx/Final-Papers/pdf/Monti_DAFX00poster.pdf) - by Monti - is quite clear to me:

[image: autocorrelation formula]

It runs a sum over the time axis.

The [second](http://academics.wellesley.edu/Physics/brown/pubs/acptrv89P2346-P2354.pdf) one by Brown makes no sense to me:

[image: narrowed autocorrelation]

How is time $t$ collapsed as a dimension? Is there an implicit sum? As it stands, the only way I can interpret this is as a multi-dimensional surface with two independent variables, $t$ and $\tau$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autocorrelation function of a random process $x(t)$ is defined as $$R(t,\tau) = {\mathbb E}\{x(t) x(t+\tau)\}.$$

For a *stationary* random process, this function does not depend on $t$, i.e., we have $R(t,\tau) = R(\tau) \; \forall t$. The correlation only depends on the time difference between two samples, not the "absolute" time $t$ when the correlation is measured.

For a *stationary* and *ergodic* process, ensemble averaging can be replaced by time averaging and we have $$R(\tau) = \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \int_T x(t) x(t+\tau) {\rm d}t,$$ which in the discrete case collapses to the sum you were showing.

The expression mentioned by Brown is a function of $t$ and $\tau$, no doubt about that. However, Brown argues (I haven't followed through the arguments, but they should be in [the second paper he was citing](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1121/1.397363)) that the expression can be used to compute a "narrowed autocorrelation function" (what ever that is) and that if viewed as a function of $\tau$ it has peaks when $\tau$ is equal to multiples of the period $T$ of the periodic signal $f(t)$. This sounds like the particular choice of $t$ is irrelevant, which makes sense if we consider $f(t)$ to be stationary and ergodic. Then again, the notation if not really rigorous. It is worth reading some more though because a few equations later he introduces the bracket notation $\langle \cdot \rangle$ for an average over a period $T$. That would make a lot of sense for his definition of $S(\tau)$ too. In fact, if we do open [Brown et al 1989](http://academics.wellesley.edu/Physics/brown/pubs/acv85_P1595-P1601.pdf) in equation (1b) he does include the $\langle \cdot \rangle$ notation. Maybe it was forgotten in the other paper?

Comment: _the discrete case collapses to the sum you were showing_ - I see. That helps; the part I'm missing is how the second (generalized) form of $N$ summed terms turns out to actually multiply them. I think it's because of the squaring; the language in the paper says: _When $N$ is equal to 2 in the above equation, the conventional or standard autocorrelation function is given by the cross term with the other two terms contributing a constant shift_ - so in the end I'll have an outer sum over $t$ of an inner sum representing the expansion of a squared N-term series.

Comment: I recommend reading the Brown 1989 paper on this - I just updated the link to one without a paywall. It explains more nicely what is the intuition between the expression. Note that it is not the same as the autocorrelation function. It is a "narrowed" version that really looks differently (on purpose).